# SQL: Migrate to a temporal table where history is correct?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that includes current and historical data. I want to migrate this from the current table to a temporal table, where the history information is correct. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why INSERT with 2 SELECT?

Comment: *"I would like to do this one row at a time, despite it being inefficient."* I have to ask; ***why?***

Comment: @Larnu 1) to learn, 2) to get a temporal table to not think that every record I insert is "current"

Comment: But they'll all be current anyway... It's an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` that stops a row being the "current" row. If over the course of several days insert 10,000 rows into a table, but perfo no other DML operations they'll all be the current rows, and there will be no data in the history table; as none of the rows have changed. And if you "must" (honestly just don't) you may well be "better off" with a `CURSOR`; don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: So your recommendation would be to look at CURSOR with a MERGE statement to generate the "updates" and make old records be marked as not current?

Comment: I don't know where updates come into this, @JohnStud. Your question says you want to insert to data from one table to another row by agonising row (RBAR); there is no `UPDATE` process needed to do that. If the above isn't the full picture (it seems it is not) you need to update your question.

Comment: But no, my recommendation would be to not do this RBAR; there are very few times where a `WHILE` is needed. I could probably count them on one hand.

Comment: I just want to insert a bunch of historical data into a temporal table -- the best way that would not make it so 2018 data that has since been updated 80 times is not listed as "current"

Comment: So do you have the history data as well? If not, the rask is fruitless; just insert all the data into the temporal table, as it's all current. Otherwise, Are you *actually* asking something like "I have a table that includes current and historical data. I want to migrate this from the current table to a temporal table, where the history information is correct. How can I achieve this?"?

Comment: TL;DR: This smells like an [XY Problem](//XYproblem.info). What is the *real* problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help immensely

Comment: You can associate a pre-populated history table with an existing table. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15#alter-non-temporal-table-to-be-a-system-versioned-temporal-table.